# iOS Speech Framework EARErrorDomain Code=0

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

Xcode 12.3
iOS 14.3
iPad Mini gen. 5

Context:
In our app, we use voice as the main input for users to navigate the functionalities. Each time they're expected to provide input, the app calls `start()` to create a fresh instance of `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest`, which is used to instantiate a `recognitionTask`. Once voice input is recognized, `stop()` is called, which calls `recognitionTask.cancel` or `recognitionTask.finish` (See below).

```
func start(resultHandler: @escaping ResultHandler) throws {
    switch self.state {
    case .stopping:
        throw SpeechSessionError.notReadyToStart
    case .started:
        throw SpeechSessionError.invalidState
    case .unconfigured, .stopped:
        break
    }
    self.resultHandler = resultHandler

    self.sawBestTranscription = false
    self.mostRecentlyProcessedSegmentDuration = 0
    let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest.init()
    if recognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition {
        print("SpeechSession: Using on-device recognition")
        request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
    } else {
        print("SpeechSession: Using remote recognition")
        // Don't assign value to attribute
    }
    self.request = request

    if self.state == .unconfigured || self.state == .stopped {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: .interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: [.notifyOthersOnDeactivation])

        let node = self.audioEngine.inputNode
        let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        node.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { [weak self] (audioPCMBuffer, _) in
            self?.request?.append(audioPCMBuffer)
        }
        self.state = .stopped
    }

    print("SpeechSession start()")
    try self.audioEngine.start()
    let task = self.recognizer.recognitionTask(with: request, delegate: self.recognizerDelegate)
    self.task = task
    self.state = .started
}

func stop(continueDeliveringTranscriptions: Bool) throws {
    guard self.state == .started else { throw SpeechSessionError.invalidState }
    print("SpeechSession stop()")
    self.state = .stopping(continueDeliveringTranscriptions: continueDeliveringTranscriptions)
    
    self.audioEngine.stop()
    self.request?.endAudio()
    if continueDeliveringTranscriptions {
        self.task?.finish()
    } else {
        self.task?.cancel()
        self.state = .stopped
    }
}
```

Problem:
The app would work normally at first. After 30 minutes or so, the bug would appear after `start()` is called and voice input is provided; instead of transcribing the voice input, it triggered the `didFinish` handler with the error `Error Domain=EARErrorDomain Code=0 "Quasar executor C++ exception: 0x2d102dc28: Could not vm_allocate 4194304 of N5kaldi6quasar9TokenHeap11ForwardLinkE: 3`

This error is not mentioned anywhere. Googling didn't return any relevant result. Does anyone know where this error is coming from and how to get around it?